# Prior art and very broad description

Tags: prior-art-request, prior-art, broad-patent, us20160288972

In reference to the patent: [US20160288972](https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/US_2016_0288972_A1)

the following links we believe show proof of prior art:
http://survco.com/credit-card-ax/

http://www.sparrowslockpicks.com/product_p/ccard.htm

https://store.itstactical.com/its-entry-card.html

http://www.knifecountryusa.com/store/manufacturer/879/touch-of-ginger.html
These are just a few we have many more that we have found.

Comment: Really not sure what your question is...

Comment: I believe this is a prior art request or else confirmation that the cited art is sufficient prior art to keep the application from issuing. It may be OK as a question if the question could be made more explicit.

Comment: Please remember that this is an application, not a patent. You need to focus on the claims. Claims on applications are often much broader than the resulting patent (should it be granted).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a patent yet but still an application, so it hasn't been examined.

Only during ther examination is a patent application checked for novelty and non-obviousness. It might be that the examiner finds this patent to be obvious over the prior art and rejects it.

If you want to help the examiner / make sure / provide prior art to the examiner, this site is not the right place.

There is however a tool in place, it's called third party observations and can be found [here](https://www.uspto.gov/patent/initiatives/third-party-preissuance-submissions).

If you submit an observation please make sure to include reasoning as to how the prior art anticipates which claims/part of the claims to maximize your chances of the examiner considering your submission.